# PHP get sum using explode function

Tags: php, explode

What is the best option to get sum between < and > from string "101<600/1200>102" which is 1800 with explode function?

```
array_sum(explode('/', explode('>', explode('<', $panel)[1])[0]))
```

I have this code this far, but sometimes i get error couse left or right numbers with these characters <,> can be or not.. Can anyone help me?

Comment: It probably would be easily to just grab all numbers between <> and then sum them together.

Comment: You mean the nos 101 and 102 are optional. But the < and > signs will always be there, right?

Comment: No, this signs gous together with these numbers 101..102

Comment: So the input will be either this, or simply 600/1200. Right?

Comment: Yes ;) or just 1800

Answer (score 1):

Try It,

$panel = "101<600/1200>102";

preg_match('~<(.*?)>~', $panel, $output);

$result = array_sum(explode('/',$output[1]));